# Angular JS - How to safely retain global value "extracted" using a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I need an object to be globally accessible all throughout my Angular application, and I've gladly put this object in a value service.
Unfortunately, this object is computed by another service, and I've not been able to inject `myService` into same `value` service.

ATM, I've acheived my goal with something like this:

**global service code**

```
app.service('myService', function() {
    this.foo = function() {
        // some code that returns an object
        return computedObject
    }
})

app.run(function ($rootScope, myService) {
    $rootScope.global = {dbObject: myService.foo()}
})
```

And which I can use in any controller that pleases me by simply injecting `$rootScope` in it

However, I don't like the need of injecting the whole `$rootScope` wherever I need that damn object, and I trust is not much safe (or efficient?) either, since the team specifies

> Of course, global state sucks and you should use $rootScope sparingly, like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to put a function on $rootScope, it's almost always better to put it in a service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily tested.
>
> Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data.

Do you, perchance, happens to know any way I can inject a service into a service value?

Or maybe any other Angular best practice which I could exploit?

---

**I forgot one very important notice**

The computation of the object could be quite computational intense, so I absolutely don't want it to be recomputed everytime I move from page to page, or anything else really.

Comment: Can you show in example about: `Unfortunately, this object is computed by another service, and I've not been able to inject myService into same value service.`

Comment: Why can you not cache the `computedObject` in your `myService` and expose the value using the method `foo` as you have done. Whoever wants data can call the method `foo`.

Comment: @MaximShoustin I've wrote it in the code.
In the first part I compute the object and in the second part I store it in the `$rootScope`  

I would have done something like this (made up syntax, ofc)  

`app.value( [myService], 'dbObject', myService.foo() )`

Comment: Its not good idea to use `rootScope` even if it's easy. I changed answser and added some code

Comment: Downvoted for what???
Is my question answered elsewhere?

Comment: Agreed - whoever downvoted should explain. Upvoted to compensate as it's a decent question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally Using $rootScope for storing a few globally required values is totally ok. But if you are still adamant on using a module, I suggest you use a provider. 
Make your 'myService' a provider and that will let you configure the variables in the service.

More info here 
[AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

Comment: I guess a `factory` could suite my well enough, but I wonder, can you tell me what's the advantage on injecting the `$rootScope` ?

Answer (score 0):

> I need an object to be globally accessible all throughout my Angular application

I would use `service`. Since Service is singleton you can register the service to all your controllers and share any data over `service`.

> Unfortunately, this object is computed by another service, and I've not been able to inject myService into same value service.

Just create one main service (Parent) and child service that will inherit the parent. (like abstract service in Java world).

```
Application.factory('AbstractObject', [function () {
   var AbstractObject = Class.extend({
        virtualMethod: function() {
           alert("Hello world");
        },
        abstractMethod: function() { // You may omit abstract definitions, but they make your interface more readable
           throw new Error("Pure abstract call");
        }
    });

    return AbstractObject; // You return class definition instead of it's instance
}]);

Application.factory('DerivedObject', ['AbstractObject', function (AbstractObject) {
    var DerivedObject = AbstractObject.extend({
        virtualMethod: function() { // Shows two alerts: `Hey!` and `Hello world`
            alert("Hey!");
            this._super();
        },
        abstractMethod: function() {
            alert("Now I'm not abstract");
        }
    });
    return DerivedObject;
}]);
```

Now, we can add some logic into `AbstractObject` and continue use `DerivedObject`
Here is example [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rAtVGAsNYggBhNADMeoT?p=preview)

Comment: Did you literally read the first half of the first sentence then stop? Edit:
I need an object to be globally accessible all throughout my Angular application, and **I've gladly put this object in a value service.**

Comment: 1st off i did read all question. Second - i didnt finish. 3d, its not so good to use `rootScope` (sure u can)

Comment: @EdHinchliffe and what after? I try to convince him to use service but not root scope. Downvote means: my answer is wrong, and please, explain why my answer is wrong. Thanks

Comment: Downvote doesn't mean your answer is wrong. It means it isn't useful. The first sentence of the question stated that the asker was using a service. Your answer at the time contained only "use a service", with a quote for half of the first sentence.

You have now modified your answer enough that it is useful again, hence I've removed your downvote. Try not submitting an answer until it's complete, or at least complete enough to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$broadcast` to send the value from the `value` service to `myService`.

You would still need to inject `$rootscope` into each of the services, but from then on you could just inject `myService` around the rest of the app.

[Reference here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24broadcast).

Comment: Actually the value already is in `myService`, or at least the function which computes it.  

It's the other way around I need

Comment: I don't get why you can't just store the computed value on the service itself? I.e. `this.bar = this.foo();` then just use `myService.bar`?

Comment: There's no reason I can't, but i have two question:
1) I may need the value **before** the service is injected in the controller. Can I still have it?
2) Does the value get recomputed every time I call a controller or, since the service is a singleton, it gets computed only once?

Comment: 1) you wouldn't be able to access it from the controller until you inject it, but you can of course access it from wherever else you can access the singleton.

2) The value would only get computed when you call the `foo` method.  It will get called once when the service is initially created (i.e. the `this.bar=this.foo()` code), but that will only happen once (singleton).